# BASH: how to ftp a variable of filenames

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to upload multiple files to a remote server via FTP.

The file names have been extracted into a variable and are separated by a single space, example:

```
testVideo.mp4 testVideo2.mp4
```

How can I get these file names to be used by 'put' or 'mput' for example to transfer the files themselves to the remove server?

This works:

```
var="testVideo.mp4 testVideo2.mp4"
mput $var
```

Much obliged for any help.

Comment: could use scp `scp $var me@thisplace:/dir1/dir2`

Comment: already using ftp though, it will take me ages to test and get scp working (still a noob) - thanks though

Comment: Do you have an SSH key or do you have to type the password when you connect to the other server ?

Comment: @Jidder - what difference would this make, no, its plain ftp and I log in automatically by    'user $USER $PASS'   ...

Comment: This works:
var="testVideo.mp4 testVideo2.mp4"
mput $var

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a string to hold the list of file names is fundamentally flawed, since a filename could contain a space. (Does `var="foo bar.mp4 baz.mp4"` contain two or three filename?) Instead, use an array:

```
var=( "testVideo 1.mp4" "testVideo 2.mp4" )
mput "${var[@]}"
```

The quoted expansion of the array guarantees that if any element of the array itself contains whitespace, that element will be properly quoted as a single argument to `mput`.

Comment: I get this as my result: ... local: testVideo 1.mp4 testVideo 2.mp4 remote: testVideo 1.mp4 testVideo 2.mp4
ftp: local: testVideo 1.mp4 testVideo 2.mp4: No such file or directory ...

Comment: This worked: ${arr[*]} rather than "${arr[@]}" - thanks, without this guidance I could not have done it

Comment: Using `*` instead of `@` should *not* work if the filenames actually have spaces, since then `mput` receives a single argument rather than 2 distinct file-name arguments.

Answer (score 0):

`ncftpput` can accept a list of local filenames, and ftp them to a remote host.  See http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/doc/ncftpput.html